# Unable to execute a REST method from workbench

Tags: security, apexrest

I am getting the following error when I make a request to a REST service.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 22:09:03 GMT 
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 
https: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:; font-src https: data:; report-uri /_/ContentDomainCSPNoAuth?type=mydomain 
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=kw0ZVMmYQd-bdOG7dDJl0g;
Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;
Expires=Sun, 17-Apr-2016 22:09:03 GMT 
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

If I execute this same request using a tool like SoapUI or Postman, it works. What do I need to do?

Comment: are you calling any external rest api or api created inside SFDC

Comment: api created in salesforce.